# Acer Netbook dont see the Battery in the Power Meter in windows XP, how to fix that?

Tags: windows-xp, battery

i have an Acer netbook AO756-2899.
its not supposed to work with windows XP but i found out the drivers for windows XP on http://www.driverstools.com/acer-drivers/driver-acer-aspire-one-ao756-netbook-for-windows-xp/
and i downloaded the chipset and graphic drivers directly from intel.com site.

all the drivers in the device manager are found and installed.
but the problem is that when i open the Power Meter there is no battery there.
and the system thinks its on AC Power while its actually using a battery.

any hints on how to fix this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Battery controller chip is connected to SMBus interface and you are missing the proper driver for it. To make it working you need a proper combination of BIOS(provides low level ACPI support), chipset driver(provides SMBus driver), Operating system (provides ACPI driver and Battery manager). My guess is that the BIOS has buggy/incomplete DSDT which is breaking SMBus in WinXP. Try updating your BIOS and if that wouldn't help - your best bet would be going back to Windows 7.

Update:
It seems like Acer does not even bother with proper driver support. They just made a proprietary application which works with SMBus controller in ICH directly without any drivers. You should try to find a version of `Acer ePower Management Application` compatible with both Windows XP and your netbook.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will try ur suggestions and see if it works.